# Unable to reuse node-mongodb-native client after first close

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to write a small class that use the native client of Mongo on Nodejs, but when I have tried to close the connection and then have opened  again (with the same client object) the operations fails, saying that the connection was closed (but I just opened).

#### So whats happen ?

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
let client = new MongoClient(urlMongoDbInstance)
await client.connect();
console.log(await client.db.(dbName).collection().findOne({}));
// [CONSOLE]
// prints object
client.close();
```

After close the connection I try to open it.

```
await client.connect();
/* [CONSOLE]
the options [servers] is not supported
the options [caseTranslate] is not supported
the options [dbName] is not supported
the options [mode] is not supported
the options [tags] is not supported
the options [hedge] is not supported
the options [preference] is not supported
the options [isValid] is not supported
the options [slaveOk] is not supported
the options [equals] is not supported
the options [toJSON] is not supported
*/
```

Then try to use the database connection

```
console.log(await client.db.(dbName).collection().findOne({}));
// [CONSOLE]
// MongoError: Topology is closed, please connect
```

#### What I know (or think I know) or found

I know that is a good practice keep the connection open while the app is running, but is not about that.

I have tried to create a new variable to connect every time and works (but that is not the idea here).

I have found an entry on Mongo about it (seems the same problem) https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-2544

#### Question?

Have anyone found a workaround on this, maybe I am not using the driver like it has to be used ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a known issue in the node driver.

You should be able to work around it by recreating the client object from scratch (rather than trying to reconnect an existing client that was disconnected).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is not a issue (or partial) after all, I arrived at the api [reference](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/MongoClient.html) and see the available options for `db` object

> `db(dbName, options)`
>
> Create a new Db instance sharing the current socket connections. Be aware that the new db instances are
> related in a parent-child relationship to the original instance so that events are correctly emitted on child
> db instances. Child db instances are cached so performing `db('db1')` twice will return the same instance.
> You can control these behaviors with the options `noListener` and `returnNonCachedInstance`.

Then it could be the cached instance resolving the closed connection so using the db as

```
await client.db(dbName, {returnNonCachedInstance : true});
```

**Works as expected**, it gives me messages but seems to not interfere.

```
the options [servers] is not supported
the options [caseTranslate] is not supported
the options [dbName] is not supported
the options [mode] is not supported
the options [tags] is not supported
the options [hedge] is not supported
the options [preference] is not supported
the options [isValid] is not supported
the options [slaveOk] is not supported
the options [equals] is not supported
the options [toJSON] is not supported
```

Thanks!